# Two linear layouts in a layout resource file but only one displays

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have already seen the same question but the answer did not held me that much. I am new to android app development and I have the following problem. From the two linear layouts only the first one displays. Can anyone help? Thank you in advance!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/home"
tools:context="dmst.allamoda.Login"
android:weightSum="1">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
    android:gravity="top|right">

    <Button
        android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="@string/button_home"
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:textColor="#ffffd1"
        android:onClick="signupControl"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <Button
        android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="@string/button_profile"
        android:id="@+id/profile"
        android:textColor="#ffffd1"
        android:onClick="signupControl"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo_image"
        android:background="@drawable/allamodalogo"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxHeight="50dp"
        android:maxWidth="50dp"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:minWidth="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:background="@drawable/post">
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your second linear layout with this code below

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:background="@drawable/post">
```